# Visual Studio Obfuscation

Tags: visual-studio, obfuscation, decompiling

I am trying to test different obfuscators. Before obfuscating I used Reko decompiler. It seems that the exe is already obfuscated - please look at the screen shot. Can someone please explain - why all the methods and variables seems as if the exe is already obfuscated?[image]

Comment: There is no point in obfuscating machine code.

Answer (score 2):

1. Symbol names are not compiled into executable machine code.
   They can be preserved, but in this case they are saved in separate .pdb file. If you don't generate it during build, or don't make available to debugger/decompiler, it cannot figure out variables and function names (except for the imported/exported ones)
2. High level constructs, like `for` or `while` are implemented with jumps and conditional jumps, so it is not possible to figure out if a loop was implemented via `for` or `goto` or if a conditional was `if` statement or ternary operator.
3. Optimization hugely transforms code, throwing away unnecessary parts, making some operations at compile time, etc.

Comment: Thanks. So in this case I can send the exe to someone without obfuscating?

Comment: Depends on how much confidence do you need. Obfuscators are supposed to make it still more obfuscated. But everything that can be executed can be reverse-engineered anyway